# Call a HTMLs Javascript function by POST'ing

Tags: javascript, html, linux, function, post

Since i would like to synchronize my proprietary router with my linux server to guarantee a constant uptime of the services, i need to restart the router or disconnect and reconnect somehow.
Buried down in the frames javascript there is a function to disconnect and reconnect the router. 
How can i call this javascript function from the linux server? Is it possible to POST call the function in some way? Any workarounds?
I've googled a bit, but was not able to find anything valuable. Maybe i tried the wrong keywords?! Please point me into the right direction
Thanks

Comment: Won't you be unable to restart the router from the Linux box, if the network goes down? I imagine it's getting an IP from the router, so no router, no route to the router to reset.

Comment: A restart (on and off, DHCP automatically enables) or reconnect (disconnect and connect) would do the trick. Both have javascript functions

Comment: If the javascript does an HTTP request to another page that actually does the restarting, then you can hit that page directly with any GET or POST parameters it expects.  If the Javascript code actually does the restarting itself, then you'll need a javascript engine to run the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your router is probably some sort of linux box, and you can't restart it with just a javascript. Most likely that javascript calls some other CGI script on the backend that does some `system('/usr/sbin/reboot -r now')` call. So you just need to call that backend script with the right parameters and right credentials. Good luck